# Starting a thread in a ROS node doesn't work without a ROS_WARN

Tags: c++, multithreading, ros

ROS Indigo with Ubuntu14.04

I am now writing a ros program and try to start a thread in a ROS node,
In the main function, I start a thread using
`std::thread my_process{process};`
The strange thing is, if I add a ROS_WARN or a cout at the very beginning, everything work fine, if I comment that line, no other output can be found (neither cout nor cv::imshow).
I am not sure what lead to this problem, is the process moved to the background completely or just not being executed? Can anyone help?

My code looks like this

```
void process() {
        while (true) {
            if (raw_image_buf.empty() || depth_image_buf.empty())  {
               ROS_WARN("Loop skipped");
               // std::cout << "\nLOOP SKIPPED\n";
            } else {
               ROS_WARN("Thread loop");
               cv::Mat raw_img, depth_img;
               ri_buf.lock();

               if (!raw_image_buf.empty()) {
                  raw_img = raw_image_buf.front().first;
                  rawstamp = raw_image_buf.front().second;
                  cv::imshow("raw", raw_img);
                  raw_image_buf.pop();
               }
               ri_buf.unlock();
               di_buf.lock();
               if (!depth_image_buf.empty()) {
                 depth_img = depth_image_buf.front().first;
                 depthstamp = depth_image_buf.front().second;
                 cv::imshow("depth", depth_img);
                 depth_image_buf.pop();
               }
               di_buf.unlock();
            }
       }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
     ros::init(argc,argv, "mynode");
     ros::NodeHandle n("~");
     ros::console::set_logger_level(ROSCONSOLE_DEFAULT_NAME, 
            ros::console::levels::Info);
     ros::Subscriber sub_raw_img = n.subscribe("image_raw", 100, 
            raw_img_callback);
     ros::Subscriber sub_depth_img = n.subscribe("image_depth", 100, 
            depth_img_callback);
     std::thread estimation_process{process};
     ros::spin();
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please edit the post to include all the related code in text format?

Comment: @mikkola Thanks for your remind  :)

Comment: I hope do sth does include a sleep otherwise the thread will never ever stop and if fast enough nothing will be brought up... can u include in the code what exactly is happening inside that do sth.

Comment: @Vtik Thanks for your comment ! Inside that loop, I simply get two image from the corresponding queue. My code is updated.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong with your codes. I tried running the exact same thing, with the global variables and callbacks defined and without any ROS_WARN, it worked for me. The LOOP SKIPPED from cout is shown and images published to the topic is shown as well (of course after adding cv::waitKey(1)). Feel free to pm me if you need any help.